# Import class from grandparent's sibling directory

Tags: python

I know there are lots of questions regarding Python relative import, but I was not able to find any of these answers helpful. So, I was hoping that the Stack Overflow Python Community could help me figure out the solution to my problem.

I have the following directory structure:

```
project
    | - src
        | - module_1
            | - module_1
                | - interesting.py
            | - __init__.py
        | - module_2
            | - module_2
                | - importhere.py
```

There are classes in the `interesting.py` module which I want to import to the `importhere.py` module. But, somehow the Pycharm doesn't let me do that!

What is the most Pythonic solution for the same?!

Comment: To clarify, `importhere.py` wants to import `interesting.py`?

Comment: Yes, it wants to import the interesting.py's class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aah, I figured out the soulution

```
project
    | - src
        | - __init__.py
        | - module_1
                | - module_1
                        | - interesting.py
                | - __init__.py
        | - __init__.py
        | - module_2
                | - __init__.py
                | - module_2
                        | - importhere.py
        | - __init__.py
```

But, is it really a good approach on having an **init**.py for the `src` directory???

Comment: The folder structure is not very clear, it seems like 3 __init__.py are under the same src folder

Answer (score 3):

If you are using python3 you can add empty `__init__.py` to each directory with files and this should work:

```
# Scary mess though, counting "." is not funny. 
from ....module_1.module_1 import interesting
```

But I would not call it pythonic. And it is ugly. The pythonic way would be to create a package instead.

I.e. a folder structure like this:

```
project
    | - src
        | - module_1
                | - module_1
                        | - __init__.py
                        | - interesting.py
                | - __init__.py <-- why do you have this one?
        | - module_2
                | - module_2
                        | - __init__.py
                        | - importhere.py
```